# Ruby 1.8: Hash#sort not return hash but array (better way to do this?)

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.8

In some scenario of Ruby 1.8. If I have a hash

```
# k is name, v is order
foo = { "Jim" => 1, "bar" => 1, "joe" => 2}
sorted_by_values = foo.sort {|a, b| a[1] <==> b[1]}
#sorted_by_values is an array of array, it's no longer a hash!
sorted_by_values.keys.join ','
```

my workaround is to make method `to_hash` for Array class.

```
class Array
  def to_hash(&block)
    Hash[*self.collect { |k, v|
      [k, v]
    }.flatten]
  end
end
```

I can then do the following:

```
sorted_by_values.to_hash.keys.join ','
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashes are unordered by definition. There can be no such thing as a sorted Hash. Your best bet is probably to extract the keys from the sorted array using collect and then do a join on the result

```
sortedByValues = foo.sort {|a, b| a[1] <==> b[1]}
sortedByValues.collect { |a| a[0] }.join ','
```

Comment: Note that hashes are ordered by key insertion order in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Dont rely on the key insertion order in 1.9, this is not a definition, its a implementation feature. If your code works with (Matz)Ruby but not with jRuby, you know what i mean :)

Comment: @Fu86: No, it's a feature of the language (confirmed by Matz). See intro of Hash's doc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html