# Sort hash by key, return hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, hashmap

Would this be the best way to sort a hash and return Hash object (instead of Array):

```
h = {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "d"=>4}
# => {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "d"=>4}

Hash[h.sort]
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's much advantage to sorting a hash, unless you are using `each` or `each_pair` to iterate over it. Even then, I'd probably still grab the keys, sort those, then iterate over them grabbing the values as needed. That ensures the code will behave correctly on older Rubies.

Comment: Makes sense in ruby 1.9 too. I had a collection of appointments grouped by dates (as keys) coming from db and i manually sorted through ruby. Eg. { "2012-09-22": [...], "2012-09-30": [...], "2012-10-12": [...] }

Comment: Yes, I find your Hash[h.sort] process more effectiv than sorting keys then accessing again the hash trough the sorted keys.

Comment: "[What is the fastest way to sort a Hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31123483/128421) will be useful.

Comment: You've had a few years to think about your solution, are you ready to accept an answer? ;-)

Comment: It's been 11 years, let's accept a solution now :P

Comment: It's hard to believe I asked this question 11 years ago! The problem is that I stopped using  Ruby long time ago and now I'm not sure which answer is the best :) `h.sort.to_h` I assume?

Answer (score 295):

In Ruby 2.1 it is simple:

```
h.sort.to_h
```

Comment: @zachaysan but it does work: `h.sort{|a,z|a<=>z}.to_h` (tested 2.1.10, 2.3.3)

Comment: @whitehat101 You are right. I had a bug (`a` is an array, not just the key). I've deleted my comment.

Comment: Just in case someone else is looking for a way to sort an array of hashes, this will do the trick (where h is the array): `h.map(&:sort).map(&:to_h)`.

Comment: I wouldn't use this solution as it's not the fastest. For small hash it's fine but for couple of thousands of keys it's 10 times slower than `h.keys.sort.map { |k| [k, h[k]] }.to_h`. Not sure where is the difference on C level, but it's very clear on benchmark. Even `sort_by(&:first)` is much faster.

Comment: @KaplanIlya Likely the difference is sorting keys vs. sorting the whole hash. Still, I prefer simplicity and brevity and would reach for this solution over something more complicated unless the hash was big enough where it was a noticeable difference. And if that's the case, sorting a hash is probably not the best architectural decision anyway :)

Comment: @MarkThomas - How does this work? Does it sort by key? Is there a reference?

Answer (score 86):

Note: Ruby >= 1.9.2 has an order-preserving hash: the order keys are inserted will be the order they are enumerated.  The below applies to older versions or to backward-compatible code.

There is no concept of a sorted hash. So no, what you're doing isn't right.

If you want it sorted for display, return a string:

```
"{" + h.sort.map{|k,v| "#{k.inspect}=>#{v.inspect}"}.join(", ") + "}"
```

or, if you want the keys in order:

```
h.keys.sort
```

or, if you want to access the elements in order:

```
h.sort.map do |key,value|
  # keys will arrive in order to this block, with their associated value.
end
```

but in summary, it makes no sense to talk about a sorted hash. From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html), "The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem arbitrary, and will generally not be in the insertion order." So inserting keys in a specific order into the hash won't help.

Comment: This is correct.  I would suggest using the RBtree gem to gain ordered set functionality in ruby.

Comment: Starting 1.9.2 hash insert order will be preserved. See http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/994

Comment: @David: very interesting, thanks!! Didn't realize this had changed.

Comment: on the last example "h.sort" should be enough.

Comment: "Starting 1.9.2 hash insert order will be preserved.", and it's sweet.

Comment: I agree that it's a sweet feature (thanks David for pointing it out), but I still feel a little funny about using it.  I'd perhaps just use the array that comes out of `h.sort` when I care about the element ordering.

Comment: @Peter: By the way, instead of `h.sort_by(&:first)` in your examples, you can just equivalently write `h.sort`.  (Docs at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002865 .)

Comment: Re my first comment (feeling funny): For example, relying on hash ordering would silently and unpredictably break for Ruby versions older than 1.9.2.

Comment: @Jo, @tokland: have amended my answer to remove the `&:first` part.

Comment: How this answer got about 20 +1's without answering not even one of the two parts of the OP question? "1) Would that (OP example) be the best way to sort a hash, 2) and return Hash object" ? I don't envy +1's :) it's just after that reading the answer I am still left with the original questions. Also if the point is that there is not such thing as a sorted hash look at the comments for choosen answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489139/ruby-1-8-hashsort-not-return-hash-but-array-better-way-to-do-this

Comment: @jj_ This question adds a lot of valuable information *around* the question. Yeah, it doesn't answer the question itself, but StackOverflow is not a Q&A site. This answer goes with the spirit of SO about collectively building answers.

Answer (score 72):

I've always used `sort_by`. You need to wrap the `#sort_by` output with `Hash[]` to make it output a hash, otherwise it outputs an array of arrays. Alternatively, to accomplish this you can run the `#to_h` method on the array of tuples to convert them to a `k=>v` structure (hash).

```
hsh ={"a" => 1000, "b" => 10, "c" => 200000}
Hash[hsh.sort_by{|k,v| v}] #or hsh.sort_by{|k,v| v}.to_h
```

There is a similar question in "[How to sort a Ruby Hash by number value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540435/how-to-sort-a-ruby-hash-by-number-value)".

Comment: using `sort_by` on a hash will return an array. You would need to map it out as a hash again. `Hash[hsh.sort_by{|k,v| v}]`

Comment: yes, the enumerator class interprets hashes as arrays I think

Comment: Note that `hsh.sort_by` passes tupples `[k,v]` into the block, so you can write `Hash[hsh.sort_by(&:first)]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland wouldn't that be `:last` then because the first of each tuple would be the key, and we want to sort by value (?? not sure)

Comment: Right, sort is on values: `hsh.sort_by(&:last).to_h => {"b"=>10, "a"=>1000, "c"=>200000}`.

Comment: Note that calling `to_h` is only supported in Ruby 2.1.0+

Comment: there is a typo in the comment, correction: `sort_by{|k,v| v}.to_h)`

Comment: You can get keys and values like this too.

Key of the smallest value:  
              `*hsh[0][0]`
First key value pair:  
               `Hash[*hsh[0]]`

Answer (score 18):

> Sort hash by **key**, return hash in Ruby

With *destructuring* and Hash#sort

```
hash.sort { |(ak, _), (bk, _)| ak <=> bk }.to_h
```

Enumerable#sort_by

```
hash.sort_by { |k, v| k }.to_h
```

Hash#sort with default behaviour

```
h = { "b" => 2, "c" => 1, "a" => 3  }
h.sort         # e.g. ["a", 20] <=> ["b", 30]
hash.sort.to_h #=> { "a" => 3, "b" => 2, "c" => 1 }
```

Note: < Ruby 2.1

```
array = [["key", "value"]] 
hash  = Hash[array]
hash #=> {"key"=>"value"}
```

Note: > Ruby 2.1

```
[["key", "value"]].to_h #=> {"key"=>"value"}
```

Comment: if not using `v` you should prefix an underscore
`hash.sort_by { |k, _v| k }.to_h`

Answer (score 16):

You gave the best answer to yourself in the OP: `Hash[h.sort]` If you crave for more possibilities, here is in-place modification of the original hash to make it sorted:

```
h.keys.sort.each { |k| h[k] = h.delete k }
```

Comment: For the curious, this runs slightly faster than the "keys sort" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17331221/737303 on Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 14):

No, it is not (Ruby 1.9.x)

```
require 'benchmark'

h = {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "d"=>4}
many = 100_000

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  GC.start

  b.report("hash sort") do
    many.times do
      Hash[h.sort]
    end
  end

  GC.start

  b.report("keys sort") do
    many.times do
      nh = {}
      h.keys.sort.each do |k|
        nh[k] = h[k]
      end
    end
  end
end

       user     system      total        real
hash sort  0.400000   0.000000   0.400000 (  0.405588)
keys sort  0.250000   0.010000   0.260000 (  0.260303)
```

For big hashes difference will grow up to 10x and more

Answer (score 6):

[ActiveSupport::OrderedHash](https://www.google.com/search?q=ActiveSupport%3A%3AOrderedHash) is another option if you don't want to use ruby 1.9.2 or roll your own workarounds.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: I fixed the link to point to Google in case some historian wants to research how this could have been done in the past. But anyone coming on this now should be using a more recent version of Ruby.

Comment: ActiveSupport::OrderedHash has been [DEPRECATED](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort` method and then convert array back to hash with `to_h` method

```rb
h = { "a" => 1, "c" => 3, "b" => 2, "d" => 4 }
h.sort.to_h
# => { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ordered = {}
@unordered.keys.sort.each do |key|
  @ordered[key] = @unordered[key]
end
```

Comment: This is how you would do this if ruby didn't have methods like Hash#sort_by

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem ( I had to sort my equipments by their name ) and i solved like this:

```
<% @equipments.sort.each do |name, quantity| %>
...
<% end %>
```

@equipments is a hash that I build on my model and return on my controller. If you call .sort it will sort the hash based on it's key value.

Answer (score -1):

I borrowed Boris Stitnicky's inspired solution to patch an in-place `sort!` method into `Hash`:

```rb
def sort!
  keys.sort!.each { |k| store k, delete(k) }
  self
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I liked the solution in the earlier post.

I made a mini-class, called it `class AlphabeticalHash`. It also has a method called `ap`, which accepts one argument, a `Hash`, as input: `ap variable`. Akin to pp (`pp variable`)

But it will (try and) print in alphabetical list (its keys). Dunno if anyone else wants to use this, it's available as a gem, you can install it as such: `gem install alphabetical_hash`

For me, this is simple enough. If others need more functionality, let
me know, I'll include it into the gem.

EDIT: Credit goes to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157237/peter), who gave me the idea. :)