# Sorting a multidimensional array with ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

Im having trouble sorting a multidimensional array in ruby and can't find any question similar to my problem.  I have an array/hash or both? (excuse me as im coming from a c/php/java background and this is my first time using Ruby)

```
user['shapeshifter'] = {age => '25', country => 'Australia'}
user['user2'] = {age => '29', country => 'Australia'}
user['user3'] = {age => '21', country => 'Russia'}
```

i want to sort the user array based on age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a hash of hashes, and ruby 1.9.2 for sorted hashes, IIRC.  This was covered in [Sort hash by key, return hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339553/sort-hash-by-key-return-hash-in-ruby)

Assuming your test case, fixed so it is valid:

```
user = {}
user['shapeshifter'] = {:age => 25, :country => 'Australia'}
user['user2'] = {:age => 29, :country => 'Australia'}
user['user3'] = {:age => 21, :country => 'Russia'}
```

All it takes is:

```
user.sort_by {|key,value| value[:age]}
```

Comment: i get this error: in `sort_by': undefined method `<=>' for #<Hash:0x7f0577f16480> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @shapeshifter It worked when I tested his example in irb. Like DGM said, you have to have Ruby 1.9.2 or higher.

Comment: That was my problem.  Sorry new to ruby didn't realise Centos would be a few versions behind.  Should have known!  Cheers.

Comment: Yeah that's an unfortunate problem with the major distors - they seem to think that ruby 1.8 is still current.  At this point everyone should be trying to run on 1.9.3 asap.

Answer (score 1):

Currently ruby 1.9 has ordered hash but still does not exist reordering function.

You can try sort pairs of arrays and than make a new Hash.
Like this

```
user = {}
user['shapeshifter'] = {:age => '25', :country => 'Australia'}
user['user2'] = {:age => '29', :country => 'Australia'}
user['user3'] = {:age => '21', :country => 'Russia'}

result1 = user.sort { |user1, user2|
  user1[1][:key] <=> user2[1][:key] # user1,2 = [key, value] from hash
}
puts Hash[result1].inspect

or this

result2 = user.sort_by { |user_key, user_val|
  user_val[:key]
}
puts Hash[result2].inspect
```