# Divide data into multiple hashes on the basis of timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a notifications page. Like any generic notification page on a social networking website. Every notification has a unix timestamp. I want to divide the notifications into multi dimensional hashes on the basis of days. The hash key can represent the day it is for . Ex :

```
notification['3July'][0] = 'Answered a question'
notification['3July'][1] = 'Answer got 13 upvotes'
notification['3July'][2] = 'Earned a badge'
....

notification['23June'][0]  = 'Set a bounty of 50 credits'
notification['23June'][1]  = 'Followed XYZ'
notification['23June'][2]  = 'Added a question on stack overflow'
```

I would then iterate through the multi dimensional hash and publish the notification under each day. Currently I get the data from a database and it is of this format :

```
notification[0] = { 'text' => 'Answered a question' , 'timestamp' => 123456 }
notification[1] = { 'text' => 'Answer got 13 upvotes'  , 'timestamp' => 123456 }
notification[2] = { 'text' => 'Earned a badge'  , 'timestamp' => 123456 }
....

notification[3]  = { 'text' =>'Set a bounty of 50 credits'  , 'timestamp' => 123456 }
notification[4]  = { 'text' =>'Followed XYZ'  , 'timestamp' => 123456 }
notification[5]  = { 'text' =>'Added a question on stack overflow'  , 'timestamp' => 123456 }
```

What is the cleanest and most optimum way to do this in Ruby/Rails ?

Comment: `Array#[]` cannot take a string as an argument.

Comment: Edited the question. Changed Array to hash.

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339553/sort-hash-by-key-return-hash-in-ruby

Comment: It's expected that you'll show code you wrote to solve this problem. See http://sscce.org for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order notifications by  timestamp, add a column to select what wil have date only and then use `group_by` in Ruby. That should be the easiest way to have it.

For selecting additional column to work you should add `attr_accessor` for it.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: Will try this out right now. Accept if it works out.

Comment: Updated the description a little.