# guarantee order of keys in hash after much manipulation

Tags: ruby

Here's my problem. Going through all these steps below you can see how the hash keys are no longer in order. In the below example, the keys are 0, 2, rather than 0,1. And I am sure with a larger data set, the situation will be worse. Is there a way I can guarantee the order of the keys in this hash?

Task:

1. If fields has something that defaults doesn't have, add it to defaults
2. If defaults has a key `k` that field does not have, remove the key-value pair with key `k` from default

Test data:

```
fields = { "0"=>{"field"=>"name", "field_type_id"=>1}, "1"=>{"field"=>"address", "field_type_id"=>2} }
defaults = {0=>"name", 1=>"email" }
```

Step 1: To find the ones in fields that are not in defaults:

```
fields_arr = fields.values.collect {|hsh| hsh['field'] }  
=> ["name", "address"]
defaults_arr = defaults.values
=> ["name", "email"]
updates = fields_arr + defaults_arr - (fields_arr & defaults_arr) - defaults_arr
=> ["address"]
```

Step 2: Update the defaults with the new fields, where the key starts from the last key of defaults:

```
i = defaults.keys.last.to_i + 1
additions = updates.reduce({}) do |acc, n|
  acc[i] = n
  i += 1
  acc       
end
defaults.merge!(additions)
=> {0=>"name", 1=>"email", 2=>"address"}
```

Step 3: Remove from defaults that which no longer exists in fields. (In other words, I have to remove "email" in this example):

```
defaults
=> {0=>"name", 1=>"email", 2=>"address"}
defaults_arr = defaults.values
removals = fields_arr + defaults_arr - (fields_arr & defaults_arr)
=> ["email"]
defaults.delete_if{|_,v| removals.include? v }
=> {0=>"name", 2=>"address"}
```

Comment: Hashes aren't meant to be orderable, if you care about order use arrays

Comment: @joseramonc But Hash also ordered In Ruby.. from when I don't know

Comment: #2 doesn't make sense. What is "it" in "remove it"? Do you mean, "If `defaults` has a key `k` that `field` does not have, remove the key-value pair with key `k` from `default`? What is your question? The last paragraph is suggestive, but you need to state you question before "Test Data". Lastly, after giving the test data, show the desired output.

Comment: @CarySwoveland #2 yes that is correct.

Comment: You need to edit your question. Don't try to clarify in comments.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I moved the question to the beginning to make it more clear.

Comment: @joseramonc, that is an opinion, not a fact. Those who lobbied successfully to have hashes maintain key-insertion order (v1.9+) would disagree I for one have found many useful applications of that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hash is ordered, but that doesn't mean it's sorted; There's a BIG difference. It's ordered because the insertion order of key/value pairs is remembered. The documentation says:

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

Sorting a hash is nonsensical; It does nothing to speed up access or insertion speed, and, if you insist on maintaining a sort order in a hash as you modify it, you're wasting CPU time.

Think of them as if they are random access devices, such as an in-memory database when reading/writing records. We can jump around without any real speed penalty and find things, insert new ones, or update them. Having them be in a sorted order makes no real difference at that point.

If you need to retrieve the keys or their associated values in a particular order, then, after you're finally finished modifying the hash, extract the keys using `keys`, order that resulting array then iterate over it or use `values_at` or simply order the result of `values`:

```
foo = {
  'z' => 26,
  'a' => 1
}

sorted_keys = foo.keys.sort # => ["a", "z"]
foo.values_at(*sorted_keys) # => [1, 26]
reverse_sorted_keys = foo.keys.sort.reverse # => ["z", "a"]
foo.values_at(*reverse_sorted_keys) # => [26, 1]
foo.values.sort # => [1, 26]
foo.values.sort.reverse # => [26, 1]
```

I'd strongly recommend reading "[Sort hash by key, return hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339553/sort-hash-by-key-return-hash-in-ruby/17331221)" and all the answers for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you want to do, maintaining the order of keys in `defaults`:

```
def modify(fields, defaults)
  fields_values = fields.values
  fields_values.each_with_object(defaults.dup) do |g,h|
    h.update(g["field_type_id"]=>g["field"]) unless defaults.value?(g["field"])
  end.select do |_,v|
    fields_values.any? { |g| g["field"] == v }
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
fields   = { "0"=>{"field"=>"name",    "field_type_id"=>1},
             "1"=>{"field"=>"address", "field_type_id"=>2} }
defaults = { 0=>"name", 1=>"email" } 

modify(fields, defaults)
   #=> {0=>"name", 2=>"address"}
```

On the other hand, if:

```
fields = { "0"=>{"field"=>"name",    "field_type_id"=>1},
           "1"=>{"field"=>"address", "field_type_id"=>0} }
modify(fields, defaults)
   #=> {0=>"address"}
```

which is possibly not what you are looking for. (If not, the question is not well-formed--no solution is possible.)

**Explanation**

For the example from the question, the steps are as follows:

```
fields_values = fields.values
  #=> [{"field"=>"name",    "field_type_id"=>1},
  #    {"field"=>"address", "field_type_id"=>2}] 

enum = fields_values.each_with_object(defaults.dup)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{"field"=>"name", "field_type_id"=>1},
  #                  {"field"=>"address", "field_type_id"=>2}]
  #     :each_with_object({0=>"name", 1=>"email"})> 

g,h = enum.next
g #=> {"field"=>"name", "field_type_id"=>1}
h #=> {0=>"name", 1=>"email"}] 

defaults.value?(g["field"])
  #=> defaults.value?("name") => true
```

therefore `h.update...` is not executed.

```
g,h = enum.next
g #=> {"field"=>"address", "field_type_id"=>2} 
h #=> {0=>"name", 1=>"email"} 
defaults.value?(g["field"]) #=> defaults.value?("address") => false
```

therefore:

```
h.update(g["field_type_id"]=>g["field"])
  #=> {0=>"name", 1=>"email"}.update(2 => "address") 
  #=> {0=>"name", 1=>"email", 2=>"address"}
```

Now perform the removals of elements from `default`:

```
enum = h.select
  #=> #<Enumerator: {0=>"name", 1=>"email", 2=>"address"}:select> 

_, v = enum.next
  #=> [0, "name"] 
fields_values.any? { |g| g["field"] == v }
  #=> fields_values.any? { |g| g["field"] == "name" } => true
```

so the key-value pair `0=>"name"` of `h` is selected.

```
_, v = enum.next
  #=> [1, "email"] 
fields_values.any? { |g| g["field"] == v }
  #=> fields_values.any? { |g| g["field"] == "email" } => false
```

so the key-value pair `1=>"email"` is not selected. Lastly:

```
_, v = enum.next
  #=> [2, "address"]
fields_values.any? { |g| g["field"] == v }
  #=> fields_values.any? { |g| g["field"] == "address" } => true
```

so the key-value pair `2=>"address"` is selected.

```
h #=> {0=>"name", 2=>"address"}
```

Comment: The thing to remember is, there is no real advantage to maintaining a sorted hash, and there are reasons to not bother, such as wasted CPU. Instead, wait until all modifications of the hash have occurred, then arrange the array of keys in the order desired, and extract the values.

Comment: @theTinMan, the maintenance of key order was a by-product of my solution. I do, however, disagree in general with your assertion, as I have found many situations where the maintenance of key order has been very useful. If what you say is true, the change in v1.9 to bestow hashes that property was pointless.

Comment: There are reasons they want insertion order maintained, which, if I remember right, was tied to some attacks that could occur on hashes, found in Perl originally but exploitable in other languages. I've *never* found a time a sorted hash was useful because I always rely on a sorted key array that enforces the order I extract from the hash. If you're going to sort it use http://stackoverflow.com/a/21413585/128421 as it's the simple path. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17331221/128421 is extremely significant though.