# What is the fastest way to sort a Hash?

Tags: ruby

People often ask what is the *best* way to sort a hash, but then they don't ask the needed follow-up question about what is the *fastest* way, which really determines the best way.

What is the fastest way to sort a Hash in Ruby, regardless of the version of Ruby being used?

I'm looking for additional answers that will cover corner cases, or uncover problems with the more generic and/or fastest methods.

Answer (score 6):

What is the fastest way to sort a Hash?

```
require 'fruity'

HASH = Hash[('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.map{ |k| [k, 1] }]

def sort_hash1(h)
  h.sort.to_h
end

def sort_hash2(h)
  Hash[h.sort]
end

def sort_hash3(h)
  Hash[h.sort_by{ |k, v| k }]
end

def sort_keys(h)
  keys = h.keys.sort
  Hash[keys.zip(h.values_at(*keys))]
end

puts "Running on Ruby v#{ RUBY_VERSION }"
puts

compare do
  do_sort_hash1 { sort_hash1(HASH) } if [].respond_to?(:to_h)
  do_sort_hash2 { sort_hash2(HASH) }
  do_sort_hash3 { sort_hash3(HASH) }
  do_sort_keys { sort_keys(HASH) }
end
```

Running the above code on a Mac OS laptop results in the following output:

```
# >> Running on Ruby v2.2.2
# >> 
# >> Running each test 256 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> do_sort_keys is faster than do_sort_hash3 by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
# >> do_sort_hash3 is faster than do_sort_hash1 by 1.9x ± 0.1
# >> do_sort_hash1 is similar to do_sort_hash2
```

And:

```
# >> Running on Ruby v1.9.3
# >> 
# >> Running each test 256 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> do_sort_keys is faster than do_sort_hash3 by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> do_sort_hash3 is faster than do_sort_hash2 by 4x ± 0.1
```

---

Doubling the hash size:

```
HASH = Hash[[*('a'..'z'), *('A'..'Z')].shuffle.map{ |k| [k, 1] }]
```

Results in:

```
# >> Running on Ruby v2.2.2
# >> 
# >> Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> do_sort_keys is faster than do_sort_hash3 by 50.0% ± 10.0%
# >> do_sort_hash3 is faster than do_sort_hash1 by 2.2x ± 0.1
# >> do_sort_hash1 is similar to do_sort_hash2
```

And:

```
# >> Running on Ruby v1.9.3
# >> 
# >> Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> do_sort_keys is faster than do_sort_hash3 by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
# >> do_sort_hash3 is faster than do_sort_hash2 by 4x ± 0.1
```

---

The values will change depending on the hardware, but the relative results shouldn't change.

[Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) was chosen over using the built-in [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) class for simplicity.

This was prompted by "[Sort hash by key, return hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4339553/128421)".

Comment: I would expect relative results to change at least somewhat depending on Ruby version and implementation, and also on size of the hash. 26 keys is not much, and any sideline n-squared factors could be hidden in this comparison.

Comment: Feel free to add additional answers scaling up the hash sizes and correcting for hidden side effects. The idea is we get some values so we can point people to how to get the most speed, at least until someone optimizes `{}.sort.to_h`

Comment: Yeah my results varied from this but still show `do_sort_keys` and `do_sort_hash3` as the fastest although over 131072 tests fruity deems them as *"similar"*.  This is on 2.1.5

Comment: Seems the larger the Hash gets the more `sort_keys` pulls in front

Comment: This is very interesting. Does it not suggest an argument for a method `Hash.sort`, based on `sort_keys`, not because of the time it takes to convert a sorted array to a hash (which is relatively small), but because there is only the need to sort on keys, rather than on 2-element arrays, which is what [Enumerable#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) does (i.e., which is unnecessary for a hash, as ties aren't broken by values)?

Comment: Maybe we should also have a method `Enumerable#sort_on_first`, whose receiver it sees as an array of arrays (hashes, for example), sorts on the first element of each contained array, returning an array of arrays.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that seems to suggest `sort_by(&:first)` which is not the same as `keys.sort`. What I am intested in testing now is how `do_sort_keys` handles something like `{[1,2,3] => 'a', [2,3,1] => 'b'}` wonder what the sort speed is on that because I think right now the speed may be associated with the simplicity of the sort but since pretty much any object can act as a key I feel this may impact this method but we will see.

Comment: @engineersmnky, not quite. `sort` is fastest when dealing with simple objects, just as integers or characters/strings. `sort_by` will rapidly pull ahead if the keys are complex objects requiring us to drill into them and extract the value being used for the sort comparison.

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm in the process of adding additional code and results to demonstrate the difference between `sort` vs. `sort_by` with simple and not-so-simple objects, but real work got in the way. :-)

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes, please disregard that comment, but it still seems like there's a case for a method `Hash.sort`, for the reason I gave in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more interesting things to consider:

```
require 'fruity'

puts "Running Ruby v#{ RUBY_VERSION }"
# >> Running Ruby v2.2.2

require 'fruity'

puts "Running Ruby v#{ RUBY_VERSION }"
# >> Running Ruby v2.2.2
```

This looks at the differences using an integer as a key:

```
HASH = Hash[[*(1..100)].shuffle.map{ |k| [k, 1] }]
compare do
  _sort1 { HASH.sort.to_h }
  _sort2 { HASH.sort{ |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }.to_h }
  _sort3 { HASH.sort{ |a, b| a.first <=> b.first }.to_h }
  _sort_by { HASH.sort_by{ |k,v| k }.to_h }
end
# >> Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _sort_by is faster than _sort2 by 70.0% ± 1.0%
# >> _sort2 is faster than _sort3 by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
# >> _sort3 is faster than _sort1 by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
```

This looks at the differences using a single-character string as the key:

```
HASH = Hash[[*('a'..'Z')].shuffle.map{ |k| [k, 1] }]
compare do
  _sort1 { HASH.sort.to_h }
  _sort2 { HASH.sort{ |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }.to_h }
  _sort3 { HASH.sort{ |a, b| a.first <=> b.first }.to_h }
  _sort_by { HASH.sort_by{ |k,v| k }.to_h }
end
# >> Running each test 16384 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _sort1 is similar to _sort3
# >> _sort3 is similar to _sort2
# >> _sort2 is faster than _sort_by by 1.9x ± 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a comparison of `sort` and `sort_by` when accessing a more complex object:

```
require 'fruity'

RUBY_VERSION # => "2.2.2"

class Foo
  attr_reader :key
  def initialize(k)
    @key = k
  end

  def <=>(b)
    self.key <=> b.key
  end
end

HASH = Hash[[*(1..100)].shuffle.map{ |k| [Foo.new(k), 1] }]
compare do
  _sort1 { HASH.sort.to_h }
  _sort_by { HASH.sort_by{ |k,v| k.key }.to_h }
end
# >> Running each test 32 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _sort_by is faster than _sort1 by 2.7x ± 0.1
```