# Sort an array by characters and numbers

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, numbers, character

I’m trying to sort an array of strings like this:

```
['A1', 'A5', 'A13', 'B2', 'B5', 'B13']
```

Of course the standard algorithm sorts it like this:

```
['A1', 'A13', 'A5', 'B13', 'B2', 'B5']
```

The problem is, there could also be strings like: `'B2K'` or `'B21A'`.

How can I get Ruby to sort these Strings in a human-logic way, like the first one. I want to achieve this without adding trailing zeros to the strings, what would be the obvious solution.

I want to understand how this could work.

Comment: @rcheetah I think that David Koelle's aphanum algorithm will be a good starting place http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html There is also a great description of how it works as well as a ruby implementation. It essentially creates "chunks" of chars as well as numbers for each item you're sorting and then compares.

Comment: If they are strings, please write so. At the moment, they are constants.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". What have you tried to solve this problem? We're here to help you but we expect you to show us your effort. http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints is also a very good read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence, you want to order the string `"A13"` as though it were the tuple `["A", 13]`. It's easy to turn `"A13"` into `["A", 13]`:

```
str = "A13"
p [ str[0], str[1..-1].to_i ]
# => ["A", 13]
```

Happily, Ruby already knows how to sort arrays like the one produced here, so all you need to do is tell it to create such an array from each string and use that in its sort comparisons. For that Ruby has [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
arr = ["B2", "A1", "A5", "B13", "A13", "B5"]

arr.sort_by do |str|
  [ str[0], str[1..-1].to_i ]
end
# => ["A1", "A5", "A13", "B2", "B5", "B13"]
```

This code assumes that each string will have one letter followed by 1 or more digits. For more complex strings like `"B21A"` you'll probably want to use a regular expression to extract each part, for example:

```
MATCH_PARTS_EXPR = /^([A-Z]+)(\d+)(.+)?/
```

This regular expression assumes each string will have one or more uppercase letters, followed by one or more digits, optionally followed by further characters. We can use it like this to e.g. turn `"B21A"` into `["B", 21, "A"]`:

```
str = "B21A"
letters, numbers, rest = str.match(MATCH_PARTS_EXPR).captures

p [ letters, numbers.to_i, *rest ]
# => ["B", 21, "A" ]

str2 = "A13"
letters, numbers, rest = str2.match(MATCH_PARTS_EXPR).captures

p [ letters, numbers.to_i, *rest ]
# => ["A", 13]
```

We can use it with `sort_by` just as before:

```
arr = ["B2", "B21A", "A1", "A5", "B13", "A13", "B5"]

arr.sort_by do |str|
  letters, numbers, rest = str.match(MATCH_PARTS_EXPR).captures
  [ letters, numbers.to_i, *rest ]
end
# => ["A1", "A5", "A13", "B2", "B5", "B13", "B21A"]
```

Comment: maybe stick a bang`!` in there too?

Comment: Sure, if you want to sort in-place, use `sort_by!`.

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please take a moment to leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I would appreciate the opportunity to improve it.

Comment: Sometimes people downvote because they got a whole bag of them and are trying to prove they're cool by sprinkling them around. Good answers always gain votes; Answer to the best of your ability.

Comment: You should probably explain why `sort_by` is preferable over `sort` for this. It's an important concept for this type of sorting task.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan; I've edit my answer to better explain what `sort_by` does.

Comment: Well... you didn't really explain *why* to use `sort_by` vs. `sort`. `sort` would compute the sort criteria for every comparison, which is costly when we're not sorting base objects. `sort_by` performs a "[Schwarzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)" which maintains the intermediate computed value, avoiding the need to recompute it each time. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31123483/128421