# Issue with nested data in JSON converted from CSV

Tags: ruby, json, csv

I am attempting to take a CSV file of the following structure:

```
item id,description,price,cost,price_type,quantity_on_hand,modifier_1_name,modifier_1_price,modifier_2_name,modifier_2_price,modifier_3_name,modifier_3_price
111010,Coffee,$1.25,$0.80,system,100000,Small,-$0.25,Medium,$0.00,Large,$0.30
111784,Delivery,,,open
111022,Bagel,$3.45,$2.00,system,9855,Cream Cheese,$1.00
```

and convert it into nested JSON. I'm learning as I go here so have been working off other people's scripts. So far I have done the following:

```
JSON.pretty_generate(CSV.open('./test/example.csv', headers: true).map do |row|
    modifier = {}
    row.each do |key, value|
        if key =~ /modifier_(.*)$/
          (modifier[$1] ||= {})[$2] = value
        end
    end
    row = [{ 
    item_id: row['item id'],
    description: row['description'],
    price: row['price'],
    cost: row['cost'],
    price_type: row['price_type'],
    quantity_on_hand: row['quantity_on_hand'],
    modifier: modifier.sort_by { |key, value| key }.map {|key, value| value }
    }]
    File.open("./test/convertedexample.json","a") do |json_file|

    json_file.puts (JSON.pretty_generate(row));

    end
    end)
```

However this results in (this is just a segment of the returned value):

```
[
  {
    "item_id": "2847233",
    "description": "Rolls 57",
    "price": "$81.43",
    "cost": null,
    "price_type": "system",
    "quantity_on_hand": "0",
    "modifier": [
      {
        "": "Jelly"
      },
      {
        "": "$.75"
      },
      {
        "": "Peanut Butter"
      },
      {
        "": "$1.12"
      },
      {
        "": null
      },
      {
        "": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

whereas what i want is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 111010,
    "description": "Coffee",
    "price": 1.25,
    "cost": 0.80,
    "price_type": "system",
    "quantity_on_hand": 100000,
    "modifiers": [
      {
        "name": "Small",
        "price": -0.25
      },{
        "name": "Medium",
        "price": 0.00
      },{
        "name": "Large",
        "price": 0.30
      }
    ]
  },
```

Can anyone provide some guidance as to how i should proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `modifier: modifier.sort.to_h` ? [Sort hash by key, return hash in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339553)

Comment: Could you provide more detail if possible and some working code as I am really stumped by this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a simpler way to do it, but I thought this would be a fun exercise.

```
require "csv"
require "json"

csv = CSV.open("./test/example.csv", headers: true)
mapping = csv.to_a.map(&:to_hash)
result = mapping.map do |row|
  row["modifier"] = []
  numbered_groups = []
  modifier_keys = row.keys.select { |key| key.match(/^modifier(.+)/) }
  modifier_keys.each do |modifier|
    base, number, property = modifier.split("_")
    numbered_groups << {number: number, property: property, value: row[modifier]}
  end
  grouped_results = numbered_groups.group_by { |group| group[:number] }
  grouped_results.each do |key, value|
    modifier_hash = {}
    value.each do |group|
      modifier_hash[group[:property]] = group[:value]
    end
    row["modifier"] << modifier_hash
  end
  modifier_keys.each do |modifier|
    row.delete(modifier)
  end
  row
end

result = JSON.pretty_generate(result)

puts result
```