# Sort hash by key which is a string

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

Assuming I get back a string:

```
"27,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,17,17,41,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,29,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,40,48,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,34,34,34,34,34,34,36,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,48,49,29,41,6,30,11,29,29,36,29,29,36,29,43,1,29,29,29,1,41"
```

I turn that into an array by calling

```
str.split(',')
```

Then turning it into a hash by calling

```
arr.compact.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }
```

I would get back a hash that looks like

```
{"1"=>2, "6"=>1, "39"=>23, "36"=>23, "34"=>39, "32"=>31, "30"=>18, "3"=>8, "2"=>10, "28"=>36, "29"=>21, "26"=>41, "27"=>48, "49"=>1, "44"=>4, "43"=>14, "42"=>34, "48"=>2, "40"=>9, "41"=>10, "11"=>1, "17"=>15, "12"=>1}
```

However, I'd like to sort that hash by key.

I've tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339553/sort-hash-by-key-return-hash-in-ruby).

I believe my problem is related to the fact they keys are strings.

The closest I got was using

```
Hash[h.sort_by{|k,v| k.to_i}]
```

Comment: Ruby hashes are, strictly speaking, unsorted. If you want the specific order, make an array of tuples. And if you want to sort them numerically, you should convert them to integers right after splitting.

Comment: This works instead: `str.split(',').group_by(&:itself).map {|k,v| [k,v.size]}.sort_by {|k,v| k.to_i}.to_h`

Comment: @MladenJablanović thanks for the insight, that is the best approach by mapping them to integers after splitting.

Comment: What's wrong with `Hash[h.sort_by{|k,v| k.to_i}]`???

Comment: `each_with_object` may be preferable to `inject` here...

Comment: @sagarpandya82 could you explain why would each_with_object be preferable?

Comment: `each_with_object` returns the initialized-hash by default whereas with `inject` the initialized-hash has to be explicitly returned via `;h`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Nothing wrong per se, but underneath you still have an array, converting it back to Hash. OP should know the difference between the two, and depending on intention, perhaps he does not need it as a Hash whatsoever, and the conversion back is just wasted cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you started with

```
str = "27,2,2,2,41,26,26,26,48,48,41,6,11,1,41"
```

and created the following hash

```
h = str.split(',').inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }
  #=> {"27"=>1, "2"=>3, "41"=>3, "26"=>3, "48"=>2, "6"=>1, "11"=>1, "1"=>1}
```

I removed `compact` because the array `str.split(',')` contains only (possibly empty) strings, no `nil`s.

Before continuing, you may want to change this last step to

```
h = str.split(/\s*,\s*/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
  #=> {"27"=>1, "2"=>3, "41"=>3, "26"=>3, "48"=>2, "6"=>1, "11"=>1, "1"=>1}
```

Splitting on the regex allows for the possibility of one or more spaces before or after each comma, and [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) avoids the need for that pesky `; h`. (Notice the block variables are reversed.)

Then

```
h.sort_by { |k,_| k.to_i }.to_h
  #=> {"1"=>1, "2"=>3, "6"=>1, "11"=>1, "26"=>3, "27"=>1, "41"=>3, "48"=>2}
```

creates a new hash that contains `h`'s key-value pairs sorted by the integer representations of the keys. See [Hash#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Notice we've created two hashes. Here's a way to do that by modifying `h` in place.

```
h.keys.sort_by(&:to_i).each { |k| h[k] = h.delete(k) }
  #=> ["1", "2", "6", "11", "26", "27", "41", "48"] (each always returns the receiver)
h #=> {"1"=>1, "2"=>3, "6"=>1, "11"=>1, "26"=>3, "27"=>1, "41"=>3, "48"=>2}
```

Lastly, another alternative is to sort `str.split(',')` before creating the hash.

```
str.split(',').sort_by(&:to_i).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
  #=> {"1"=>1, "2"=>3, "6"=>1, "11"=>1, "26"=>3, "27"=>1, "41"=>3, "48"=>2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hashes shouldn't be treated as a sorted data structure. They have other advantages and use case as to return their values sequentially. As Mladen Jablanović already pointed out a array of tuples might be the better data structure when you need a sorted key/value pair.

*But* in current versions of Ruby there actually exists a certain order in which key/value pairs are returned when you call for example `each` on a hash and that is the order of insertion. Using this behavior you can just build a new hash and insert all key/value pairs into that new hash in the order you want them to be. But keep in mind that the order will break when you add more entries later on.

```
string = "27,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,17,17,41,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,29,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,40,48,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,34,34,34,34,34,34,36,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,48,49,29,41,6,30,11,29,29,36,29,29,36,29,43,1,29,29,29,1,41"

sorted_number_count_tupels = string.split(',').
                                    group_by(&:itself).
                                    map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }.
                                    sort_by { |(k, v)| k.to_i }
#=> [["1",2],["2",10],["3",8],["6",1],["11",1],["12",1],["17",15],["26",41],["27",48],["28",36],["29",21],["30",18],["32",31],["34",39],["36",23],["39",23],["40",9],["41",10],["42",34],["43",14],["44",4],["48",2],["49",1]]

sorted_number_count_hash = sorted_number_count_tupels.to_h
#=> { "1" => 2, "2" => 10, "3" => 8, "6" => 1, "11" => 1, "12" => 1, "17" => 15, "26" => 41, "27" => 48, "28" => 36, "29" => 21, "30" => 18, "32" => 31, "34" => 39, "36" => 23, "39" => 23, "40" => 9, "41" => 10, "42" => 34, "43" => 14, "44" => 4, "48" => 2, "49" => 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Notes

#### compact

`String#split` cannot return a `nil` element. `compact` won't be useful, here. `split` might return an empty string, though :

```
p "1,,2,3".split(',')
# ["1", "", "2", "3"]
p "1,,2,3".split(',').compact
# ["1", "", "2", "3"]
p "1,,2,3".split(',').reject(&:empty?)
# ["1", "2", "3"]
```

#### inject

If you have to use two statements inside `inject` block, `each_with_object` might  be a better idea :

```
arr.compact.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }
```

can be rewritten :

```
arr.compact.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
```

#### Hash or Array?

If you need to sort results, an Array of pairs might be more suitable than a Hash.

#### String or Integer?

If you accept to have an integer as key, it might make your code easier to write.

## Refactoring

Here's a possibility to rewrite your code :

```
str.split(',')
   .reject(&:empty?)
   .map(&:to_i)
   .group_by(&:itself)
   .map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }
   .sort
```

It outputs :

```
[[1, 2], [2, 10], [3, 8], [6, 1], [11, 1], [12, 1], [17, 15], [26, 41], [27, 48], [28, 36], [29, 21], [30, 18], [32, 31], [34, 39], [36, 23], [39, 23], [40, 9], [41, 10], [42, 34], [43, 14], [44, 4], [48, 2], [49, 1]]
```

If you really want a Hash, you can add `.to_h` :

```
{1=>2, 2=>10, 3=>8, 6=>1, 11=>1, 12=>1, 17=>15, 26=>41, 27=>48, 28=>36, 29=>21, 30=>18, 32=>31, 34=>39, 36=>23, 39=>23, 40=>9, 41=>10, 42=>34, 43=>14, 44=>4, 48=>2, 49=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `arr.compact.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }` to a variable and sort it by key:

`num = arr.compact.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }
num.keys.sort`

That would sort the hash by key.

Comment: This wouldn't work as this would literally return an array of sorted keys only.

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby hash will keep the order of keys added. If the array is small enough to sort I would just change

```
str.split(',').
```

to

```
str.split(',').sort_by(&:to_i)
```

in order to get the values, and therefore also you hash sorted...