# Ruby calculate the percentage of elements in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, percentage, ruby-hash

I have a hash :

```
hash = {"str1"=>2, "str2"=>3, "str3"=>7}
```

I want to calculate the percentage of each element in the hash so I can get one like this :

```
{"str1"=>16.66% , "str2"=>25.00%, "str3"=>58.33%}
```

Any idea about that? Thanks

Comment: Use [`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and the linked pages and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Your question isn't asked well. Did you search? If not why? If so, where and why didn't it help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, what is the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're asking about?

Comment: @theTinMan thank you. Yes I searched and didn't find what I was looking for tha'ts why I asked. I think my question is clear enough with the example I gave. I got the answer I needed in just few minutes after asking. I don't know why the negative vote is for though ...

Comment: Hover over the arrows to see what they mean. If you searched you should say where and explain why it didn't help. That helps us avoid duplicating your effort to help you and helps others find additional sources. Getting the answer in a few minutes means you should wait to see if a better answer appears. It takes about 24 hours for all the community to see a question and formulate answers. Remember, SO isn't here to solve your problem only, it's here to document solutions for everyone in the future too, so complete questions are important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
sum = a.values.inject(0, :+) # or simply a.values.sum if you're on Ruby 2.4+
#=> 12
a.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v * 100.0 / sum }
#=> {"str1"=>16.666666666666668, "str2"=>25.0, "str3"=>58.333333333333336}
```

To have it with `%`:

```
a.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = "#{(v * 100.0 / sum).round(2)}%" }
#=> {"str1"=>"16.67%", "str2"=>"25.0%", "str3"=>"58.33%"}
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thank you very much! I added `round(2)` to get only 2 numbers after the coma. Could you please explain more the `{ |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = ` so I could understand better .. Thanks

Comment: @media I edited the answer with the link to documentation. Basically you iterate over each key-value pair (`k`,`v`) and you are creating a new object on the fly `({})` - hash. So prior the first iteration hash is empty (it's initial value we gave). On the first iteration we set the `hash["str1"]` to be equal to the calculated percentage based on the `v` (`2`). On the next iteration we set the `hash["str2"]` to eq next calculation and so on. So in the end we have new hash object.

Comment: `'%.2f%' % (v * 100.0 / sum)` might be more readable if you're used to sprintf.

Comment: @EricDuminil I was 100% sure sooner or later someone will mention that :) I used to interpolation - `'%.2f%'` reminds me of Java which I don't love much. But indeed it might look cleaner to those who used to it

Comment: In real life you'd need to deal with the case where `sum` equals zero.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer IMHO was unfortunately deleted:

```
total = hash.values.sum
hash.transform_values { |v| (v * 100.0 / total).round(2) }
```

The hash method `transform_values` is relatively unknown and this case is exactly what it is for. (Ruby 2.4+ or Rails 4.2+)

@Ursus, if you undelete yours I'll delete this. Keep in mind that answers here are not just for OP but anyone else who has the same question in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark, but my answer was pretty identical to Andrey's answer and I used the amazing `transform_values` method that is too new to put that in an answer without an alternative :)

Comment: Well I think over time it will become more and more useful. Some of my answers which required a certain version of Ruby may not have been too useful at the time, but eventually [became among my highest scoring answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339553/sort-hash-by-key-return-hash-in-ruby/22315036#22315036).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AndreyDeineko for his quick answer!
I tried to do it with an `each` method only (instead of `each_with_object`, so here is the answer.

```
sum = hash.values.sum
result = {}
hash.each { |k,v| result[k] = (v*100.00/sum).round(2)}
```

To have it with `%`:

```
hash.each { |k,v| result[k] = (v*100.00/sum).round(2).to_s + "%"}
```