# Ruby-on-Rails - Problems displaying a sorted table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table

I am new to Ruby, and working on code written by someone else. We are having to work with deprecated versions: Ruby 1.8.7, and Rails 2.3.5 - because this is a charity in the developing world and there is no capacity to upgrade.

I have a report which produces a table (a drug inventory), and need to sort it by the drug's name.

The relevant controller code looks like this:

```
all_drugs = Drug.find(:all,
                      :order => "name ASC")
@stock = {}
all_drugs.each{ |drug|
  drug_id = drug.drug_id
  first_date = Pharmacy.active.find(:first,
                                    :conditions =>["drug_id =?",drug_id],
                                    :order => "encounter_date").encounter_date.to_date rescue nil
  next if first_date.blank?
  next if first_date > @end_date

  start_date = @start_date
  end_date = @end_date

  stock_at = Pharmacy.stock_at(drug_id,end_date)
  if stock_at > 0
    last_activity = "In stock"
    else last_activity = Pharmacy.last_activity(drug_id,end_date)
  end

  drug = Drug.find(drug_id)
  drug_name = drug.name
  @stock[drug_name] = {"dispensed" => 0,"stock_at" => 0,"removed" => 0, "receipts" => 0,"prescribed" => 0,"last_activity" => 0}
  @stock[drug_name]["dispensed"] = Pharmacy.dispensed_drugs_since(drug.id,start_date,end_date)
  @stock[drug_name]["stock_at"] = stock_at
  @stock[drug_name]["removed"] = Pharmacy.total_removed(drug.id,start_date,end_date)
  @stock[drug_name]["receipts"] = Pharmacy.total_delivered(drug.id,start_date,end_date)
  @stock[drug_name]["prescribed"] = Pharmacy.prescribed_drugs_since(drug.id,start_date,end_date)
  @stock[drug_name]["last_activity"] = last_activity
}
```

The relevant view code looks like this:

```
<%count = 1
@stock.each{|name,values|
  prescribed = values["prescribed"]
  receipts = values["receipts"]
  dispensed = values["dispensed"]
  removed = values["removed"]
  stock_at = values["stock_at"]
  last_activity = values["last_activity"]
%>

  <tr>
    <td class="color_<%=color%>"><%=name%></td>
    <td class="color_<%=color%> caldata" id="stock_at_<%=count%>"><%=stock_at%></td>
    <td class="color_<%=color%> caldata" id="removed_<%=count%>"><%=removed%></td>
    <td class="color_<%=color%> caldata" id="prescribed_<%=count%>"><%=prescribed%></td>
    <td class="color_<%=color%> caldata" id="dispensed_<%=count%>"><%=dispensed%></td>
    <td class="color_<%=color%> caldata" id="last_activity_<%=count%>"><%=last_activity%></td>
    <td class="color_<%=color%> caldata" id="receipts_<%=count%>"><%=receipts%></td>
  </tr>
  <% count+=1
}%>
```

This happily produces the correct table but in a random order (re-starting the server and reloading the page will give the table in a new order).

I have tried a variety of options found online. I tried `@stock.all.order` (doesn't work in Rails 2.x), `@stock.find` (doesn't accept 2 arguments, `:all` and `:order`, and using just `:order` doesn't help), `@stock.sort` (no effect), and `@stock.sort_by` (no effect). All of those placed either at the end of the controller code or just before the `@stock.each` in the view code.

I have to say I am particularly baffled that the order is random - I would have presumed that even if I was failing to order it by name, the order would still be consistent...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try .sort ?

Comment: Yep, thank you, I tried both `.sort` and `.sort_by` on @stock - I'll update the question to clarify that. I tried a simple @stock.sort, as well as some variations such as `@stock.sort_by { |a| a[0] }`, and `@stock.sort{|a,b| b[:name] <=> a[:name]}`, based on other answers I'd found on this site. None worked, but of course I may have got the syntax wrong. In particular I am not confident that I fully understand the structure and indexing of the @stock array.

Comment: `@stock` is not an array. It is an instance variable, that was declared as a Hash: `@stock = {}`. You probably want to `@stock.sort_by { |k,v| v }`, or just `@stock.keys.sort.each { |k| }`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me, I had missed that distinction! Unfortunately neither of these solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are unordered by definition in ruby 1.8.7(please check [Ruby 1.8: Hash#sort not return hash but array (better way to do this?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489139/ruby-1-8-hashsort-not-return-hash-but-array-better-way-to-do-this)) hence we have to use the order as array. There can be no such thing as a sorted Hash. in your view change the line

```
@stock.each{|name,values|
```

to

```
@stock.sort_by {|s, v| s.downcase}.each{|name,values|
```

Comment: Thank you, but this made no difference - the list is still unsorted.

Comment: can you dump the "@stock" variable and send me the first 3 rows, 'puts @stock'

Comment: Start of the dump looks like this (dummy data of course):
{"Paracetamol (250mg)"=>{"receipts"=>10000.0, "prescribed"=>0, "dispensed"=>0, "last_activity"=>"In stock", "removed"=>0, "stock_at"=>10000.0}, "Paracetamol (1g)"=>{"receipts"=>10000.0, "prescribed"=>0, "dispensed"=>0, "last_activity"=>"In stock", "removed"=>0, "stock_at"=>10000.0}, "EFV (Efavirenz 600mg tablet)"=>

N.B. I reloaded the server a couple of times and each time the order of the drugs varies.

Comment: Please try     Hash[@stock.sort_by {|s, v| s.downcase}].each{|name,values|  -- Don't forget to add the v in |s, v|

Comment: I suspect that as another hash is being created the issue with unordered hash in ruby 1.8.7 is still generating a 'random' order of drugs in the view.

Comment: Yup that's why i am directly iterating on the newly created hash

Comment: I see, I'd like to try it (need to install 1.8.7 though). I was thinking that even if the newly created hash is sorted, when it is iterated through 'each' it results in unpredictable ordering (guess I'm wrong :) So let me rbenv install 1.8.7!

Comment: ouch.. resuscitating ruby 1.8.7 seems much harder then I thought :(

Comment: TBH, I am not sure since i didn't test on 1.8.7. if it didn't work i will pull a dockerfile with ruby 1.8.7 and give it a shot too.

Comment: I will try docker too, then, as I'm failing in all attempts to install ruby 1.8.7 on my mac and on a ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: So, here are my experiment's results on 1.8.7:

stock = {"Foo"=>3, "Bar"=>1, "Fizz"=>7, "Buzz"=>5, "Alot"=>42}
=> {"Fizz"=>7, "Alot"=>42, "Bar"=>1, "Foo"=>3, "Buzz"=>5}
irb(main):002:0> Hash[stock.sort_by {|s,v| s.downcase}].each{|key,val| puts "#{key} #{val}"}
Fizz 7
Bar 1
Alot 42
Foo 3
Buzz 5
=> {"Fizz"=>7, "Bar"=>1, "Alot"=>42, "Foo"=>3, "Buzz"=>5}

and it seems ruby 1.8.7 is messing with the hash sorting anyway (sorry but I want able to format the output properly in this comment)

Comment: This seems to be perfect, thank you!  

@patrick-de-marta - Thank you, I liked your solution too and intuitively think it would have worked. I was halfway to testing it but had to rewrite a lot of code for reasons not directly related to the problem (it was trying to display the full drug list of several hundred drugs, which was going beyond the page length and not even showing any names, etc. - all things I was sorting out but which prevented me testing it properly), sorry.  Also I feel your pain - it took me almost a full day to get Ruby 1.8.7 set up with all the deprecated dependencies...

Comment: you're welcome, happy you solved it in the easiest way for your workflow

Comment: @Phueal, great. but please consider an update, working with an obsolete version of ruby could quickly turn to a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Hash in Ruby 1.8.7 was not ordered, so you can't rely on the order of the keys in @stock.

As a workaround, first I'd query Drug selecting only **id** and **name** fields

```
all_drugs = Drug.find(:all, :select => "id, name")
```

as you are querying for single drug attributes later in the code.

Then I'd create an empty @stock_keys **array** to collect drug names, just after the     @stock hash definition

```
@stock = {}
@stock_keys = []
```

and push drug names in it, right after your query for drug_id

```
drug = Drug.find(drug_id)
drug_name = drug.name
@stock_keys << drug_name 
@stock[drug_name] = ...
```

At the end of the iteration on **all_drugs**, in your controller, I'd sort the @stock_keys array

```
@stock_keys.sort!
```

Then, in the view, I'd iterate over the @stock_keys array, retrieving at each step the drug's values from the @stock hash

```
 @stock_keys.each do |name|
    values = @stock[name] 
    prescribed = values["prescribed"]
    ...
 end
```

I hope this can help.